# Java loops - making a "V"

Tags: java, loops

This might sound like a slightly odd question, so bear with me.

What I'm tasked to do, is to make a simple Java class that forms a "V" based on whatever height the user would desire, made out of stars "*", and spaces " ".

For example, if a user desires a "V" with a height of 3, it would look print out something like;

```
*     *
 *   *
   *
```

Where a "V" with a height of 5 would look something like:

```
*           *
  *        *
    *     *
      *  *
        *
```

(That one didn't look too good, but you get the point, it's suppose to be 5 "high" and shaped like a "V")

The problem I have, is that I don't see what loops within loops within loops I would need to build something like this.

All the easy stuff like asking the user what height they want and such, I can handle, but I don't see how this thing is suppose to be coded, to print out a decent-looking and right-sized "V" in the console.

Can anyone assist me in this odd matter?

**UPDATE**

So in order to not come off as lazy, I tried poking around a little to see what I could come up with. Thanks to that and some help from the comments section, I came up with something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int height = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 2*(height-1)+1; j++) {

            if(j == i) {

                System.out.print("*");

            } else {

                System.out.print(" ");

            }

        }
}
```

Looked like something of a good start, and it drew me half of the "V" in the size I wanted.

Am I on to it here, or am I on the moon in terms of progress?

I would love a poke in the right direction, and I do appreciate your comments guys!

Comment: assignment? you are at wrong place.

Comment: This looks like a homework question, you need to try something, show the code and explain what's not working, we can't solve the problem for you @Adi It's OK to ask homework questions, as long as they show due dilligence, which is not happening in this case

Comment: A loop goes from 0...2 aka `for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {...}` and another loop goes up to `2*(height-1)+1`, and if the index of the second loop is right then it's a star, if not then it's a space.

Comment: Describe how you would draw that V, say for 5, line by line. And then generalize: a loop for the lines, a loop counter etc. Write it down on paper. And you will see a pattern.

Comment: You need two loops, (1) which will handle number of lines, (2) which will generate content in each line (you can make your decision on how content of each line should look like based on max number of lines and current line number). Finding relation between these numbers is what you need to figure out yourself.

Comment: Have you considered that what you want to draw is symmetrical? Thay way you only need one loop - the one you have. In  the inner J loop rather than outputing in every go output to a var. e.g. 
`String t = "";
/*STUFF*/
t = t + " ";
/*STUFF*/
t = t + "*";
/*STUFF*/
outside the j loop have
System.out.print(t);
System.out.print(t.reverse());
System.out.println("");
`

That should do it. BTW: I am not sure if the reverse function works on a string but if it doesn't you can code that function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that draws V.

Look at it, you will understand why it works....

```
    void drowV(int hight){
    int rowLen = (hight-1)*2;

    for(int i=0; i<hight; i++){
        int start = i;
        int end = rowLen-i;
        for(int j=0;j<=rowLen; j++){
            if(j==end){
                System.out.println("*");
                break;
            }
            else if(j==start){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else{
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```